# How to format a date format come from MongoDB?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, react-native

I create a `react native` project that call an api to get the date data from MongoDB.

Here is my date data from MongoDB:

```
"2018-05-05T11:00:00.000Z"
"2018-05-05T13:00:00.000Z"
"2018-05-05T17:10:00.000Z"
"2018-05-05T21:00:00.000Z"
"2018-05-05T23:10:00.000Z"
```

I try to use `thedate =  new Date(value);` to get hours and minutes

When i `console.log(thedate);`

```
Sat May 05 2018 19:00:00 GMT+0800 (CST)
Sat May 05 2018 21:00:00 GMT+0800 (CST)
Sun May 06 2018 01:10:00 GMT+0800 (CST)
Sun May 06 2018 05:00:00 GMT+0800 (CST)
Sun May 06 2018 07:10:00 GMT+0800 (CST)
```

It becomes different date: 11:00 becomes to 19:00 and 05-05 becomes to 05-06

I can't figure it out.

Comment: They represent same exact date. `GMT+0800` is the local time difference in CST timezone from the UTC date in the first string

Comment: You have diffrent time zones in mongo DB there is UTC+0 (zulu - Z)  in JS you have +8 hours - but don't worry - date-time is the same but in different timezones

Comment: Thanks for reply, so it looks like i have to reduce 8 hours. But how ? Any suggestion ? Thanks.

Comment: @徐博俊 You don't have to reduce anything. As written before, the dates you have are all the same value, they are just a different representation. So the first record is 5th May 2018, 11:00 in UTC+0. So it would display 12:00 for a user in France, UK, Spain,... (UTC+0100) or 19:00 in China, Taiwan, Macau, ... (UTC+0800). So the question is what time would you like your users to see - the time in their location or time in your location? The js defaults to showing time in user's location as that's very natural.

Comment: @ZdeněkJelínek thanks for your infromation, i get it clearly now. I am in UTC+0800  , my simulator environment is UTC . So it cause me think it is a problem. Actually there is no problem. The information helps me a lot . Thank you !

Comment: I try to change my ios emulator and see my console.log. It is still -8 hours . Any idea ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Moment npm to change date format in react native.

Example:

```
npm install moment --save
```

In your code:

```
import Moment from 'moment';
Moment(new Date()).format("YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss");
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion for `react-moment` , but i find it use like a jsx tag not yours ? When i try your code show error Cannot call a class as a function.

Comment: It's m mistakes please have a look at the updated code.

Comment: The code is working now. But the time is still -8 hours. Any idea? Thanks you.

Comment: Check ypur timezone.